# XPath 2.0 exception using string-join and distinct-values

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to get the following xPath expression to work in .Net 4.8 using XPath2.0 but I can't figure out how to fix the issue as it keeps throwing an XPathException:

```
// Line below is broken down into 2 lines for visibility sake in SA.
var xPath = "fn:string-join(fn:distinct-
             values(//MyType/MyTypeNumber/alternatives/MyTypeNumber/value),',')";
var exp = nav.Compile(xPath);
```

This should return me a comma separated string and works exactly as expected when trying it with [Free Online XPath Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Note that I've tried without using `fn:`, then adding the namespace and adding `fn` in front of both xPath function, and I made sure to add the "fn" namespace as follows:

```
var xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("fn", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions");
```

But to no avail.

When I call:

```
var exp = nav.Compile(xPath);
```

It does not return an error and my `ReturnType` is set to: `Any`

But whether I call `.Select(exp)` or `.Evaluate(exp)', it always returns the following exception:

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. 
This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'
```

I thought that using the library XPath2.0 would allow me to call XPath2 functions, so what am I missing here?

Thanks

**Update-1:**

Here is a full example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var e = new XPathDocument(@"abc.xml");
            var nav = e.CreateNavigator();

            var xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
            xmlnsManager
              .AddNamespace("fn", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions");

            var xPath = "fn:string-join(fn:distinct-values(//MyType/MyTypeNumber/alternatives/MyTypeNumber/value),',')";
            var exp = nav.Compile(xPath);

            if (exp.ReturnType == XPathResultType.NodeSet)
            {
                var iterator = nav.Select(exp);
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(iterator.Current.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var value = nav.Evaluate(xPath);
                Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Library used:

[XPath2.net](https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example (rather than disconnected snippets of code). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My guess would be that you are using an XPath processor that does not support XPath 2.0. You need to tell us more about the library you are using.

Comment: Do you use [this lib](https://github.com/semyonc/xpath2) or something similar? Otherwise, I don't think you can use XPath2.0 functionality in .Net

Comment: @ConalTuohy 100% right. Apologies. Was rushing as it was 2.30am and needed to hit the sack! Anyway, I've posted an update with the sample code I'm working with. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKay I've updated my Answer and I've added the library I'm using, well I thought I was using but I just realized I was using the standard System.Xml and System.Xml.Path which probably explains why it did not work!

Comment: @JaSON You are correct but as mentioned to Michael Kay, I thought I was using this when I was not! I need to figure out how to convert the above and use the XPath2.net. If I can, I'll post an update once again.

Comment: Saxon-HE also exists (e.g. on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE) to support XPath 3.1, XQuery 3.1 and XSLT 3.0 for the .NET framework.